# swiftファイルからStoryBoardに遷移

Tags: swift3

.swiftファイルからStoryBoardにあるViewControllerに遷移したいのですが、どのように遷移するかご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、メソッド名かリファレンスをいただければと思います。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

[Class UIStoryboard](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard)
そのものズバリ、`UIStoryboard`クラスを使います。イニシアライザを含めて、3つしか項目がないので、紛れもありません。
ボタン（`goNext(_:)`）を押したら、`UINavigationController`をInitial View ControllerとするStoryboard「Next.storyboard」をインスタンス化し、遷移するコードを、サンプルとして載せておきます。

```
@IBAction func goNext(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Next", bundle: nil)
    if let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UINavigationController {
        present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

新規にStoryboardを作成した時、Initial View Controllerを指定し忘れないように、気をつけてください。Storyboardの出発点になるView Controllerを指定するのが必須で、それをInitial View Controllerと呼びます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

View ControllerのAttributes Inspectorで、「Is Initial View Controller」にチェックをつけると、矢印が示す矢印がついて、それが出発点のView Controllerであることを示します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。非常に助かりました。